# Send value in the creation entity Typescript-Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an entity like this:

```
import { BaseEntity } from './../../../shared';
import { Empleado } from '../empleado.model';

export class ReporteEmpleadoMes {
constructor(
    public mes?: string,
    public empleadosAlta?: Array<Empleado>,
    public empleadosBaja?: Array<Empleado>,
) {
    this.empleadosAlta = new Array();
    this.empleadosBaja = new Array();
  }
}
```

And I want to create an object to send the month, only the month.

And I do not see how to see it, I have looked at several forums, including courses that I have and I do not see how it is the syntax that devo applies.

```
new ReporteEmpleadoMes(//mes);
```

Can somebody help me

Comment: What's wrong with `new ReporteEmpleadoMes('abril')`?

Comment: I'm stupid, I thought I had tried it that way, and I would not have tasted it right, because it works. Thank you very much.